# What happens to Unicode in a System.Data.SQLCommand

Tags: .net, unicode, sqlcommand

I have a SQLCommand :

> "Update Customers Set Name = @name
>   where code = @code"

and this code:

```
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = "بهروز";//(some Unicode characters)  
cmd.Parameters[1].Value = 1;  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

or this code:

```
        UpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE [Customers] SET [Name] = @p1 WHERE (([Code] = @p2) AND ((@p3 = 1 AND [Name] IS NULL) OR ([Name] = @p4)))";
        UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@p1", System.Data.SqlDbType.SmallInt, 0, "Name");
        UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@p2", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0, "Code");
        UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@p3", System.Data.SqlDbType.NText, 0, "Name");
        UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@p4", System.Data.SqlDbType.SmallInt, 0, "Name");
```

and when I Select Customers Table I have lots of "?"s.
why does SQLCommand work Correct when working with a SQLDataAdapter?
How can i convert my Unicode Data to ANSI?

edit:
in other words :
what code does SQLDataAdapter use?
anyone has the source code of that part of .net framework?

Comment: What data type is that column? What tool do you use to verify the contents? Does it work if you use a SQLCommand to retrieve it with back into .NET?

Comment: What type is the Name column in the Customers table? If you check with Microsoft Management Studio or alike, does the table contain the correct data? In other words: Is the problem in the update or select part?

Comment: the first one is nvarchar.the second one is numeric(18,0).

Comment: the problem is not related to the data type.as i said before, SqlDataAdapter works correct.the reason I don't  want to use it anymore is the speed.

Comment: And in what tool do you get question marks?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server management studio 2008, 
visual studio, 
everything.

Comment: Your own program also shows question marks? Or do you mean a tooltip hovering over a variable in the visual studio debugger?

Comment: the problem is the update part.

Comment: I have the exact problem in 34 Tables.cool?

Comment: Can you check the .DbType property of .Parameters[0] after you've set the value but before you execute? (ie. cmd.Parameters[0].DbType)

Comment: as you know all the text in this site is saved in SQL.
how does it work?anyone knows?

Comment: It works by default. You have to do your best to not make it work. So the question is: What have you done to *not* make it work?

Comment: My guess is that he's using SQL Server Management Studio to verify the contents of his table, and it's not able to show his unicode characters properly. I base this on the fact that he said he has the same problem in 34 tables and somehow I doubt he altered his program 34 times to dump the contents of one table at a time into a grid. I'd like for him to verify what happens if he actually runs a select from his own program and shows it in a grid, what happens then? But "the problem is the update part", he's locked into this, so I doubt he'll be persuaded that there is a problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dear Behrooz just use a simple SQL command

N'ناصر حاجلو'

whenever you use N you forcesql to use unicode and nothing will corrept.

Answer (score 2):

All strings in .NET are Unicode.  There is no such thing as an ANSI string within .NET.  If you want a string encoded into a byte array as ANSI, use [Encoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes.aspx).

Your issue may be with the way its sending data to the stored procedure.  I think you need to add the sql datatype to the parameter. Try the following code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30);
```

See the [SqlParameterCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x.aspx) Method for more information.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess: try setting the `SqlDbType` of the parameter explicitly:

```
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = "بهروز";//(some Unicode characters)  
cmd.Parameters[0].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
cmd.Parameters[1].Value = 1;  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```