# OPENJSON unable to parse Chinese characters

Tags: sql-server, json

I'm trying to convert my JSON data into a table format in SQL Server.
Following are my JSON data:

```
[{
    "emp_no": "001",
    "emp_designation":"Data Admin",
    "emp_name": "Peter",
    "emp_name2": "彼特"
  },
  {
    "emp_no": "002",
    "emp_designation":"Software Engineer",
    "emp_name": "Lee",
    "emp_name2": "李"
  }]
```

What I had tried are:

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @JSON='[{
"emp_no": "001",
"emp_designation":"Data Admin",
"emp_name": "Peter",
"emp_name2": "彼特"},
 {
"emp_no": "002",
"emp_designation":"Software Engineer",
"emp_name": "Lee",
"emp_name2": "李"
 }]'
```

--Method 1

```
 SELECT * INTO #emp_temp FROM OPENJSON(@JSON)
 WITH (emp_no varchar(20),
 emp_designation varchar(50),
 emp_name NVARCHAR(100),
 emp_name2 NVARCHAR(100))

SELECT * FROM #Emp_temp
DROP TABLE #Emp_temp
```

--Method 2

```
SELECT 
JSON_Value (EMP.VALUE, '$.emp_no') as emp_no, 
JSON_Value (EMP.VALUE, '$.emp_designation') as emp_designation,
JSON_Value (EMP.VALUE, '$.emp_name') as emp_name, 
JSON_Value (EMP.VALUE, '$.emp_name2') as emp_name2
INTO  #Emp_temp2
FROM OPENJSON (@JSON) as EMP

SELECT * FROM #Emp_temp2
DROP TABLE #Emp_temp2
```

However, both temp table return me following result, with the Chinese characters remain as "???".
Temp table select result

emp_no  emp_designation emp_name    emp_name2

001 |Data Admin       | Peter| ??

002 |Software Engineer| Lee  |  ?

Any idea how to preserve the original Chinese characters after parse the data into temp table?

Thanks.

*Edit:
I know it can work by putting a extra 'N' in front of the JSON

```
set @JSON=N'[
    { "emp_no": "001...
   .....
```

But actually the JSON  is a parameter in a Store Procedure, I cannot simply add a N like : set @JSON = 'N' + @JSON,
which this will jeopardize the format of the JSON data, and cause an error.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_StoreEmpInfo]
 @JSON NVARCHAR(max)

 @JSON = 'N' + @JSON

/*Will cause invalid JSON format error */
SELECT 
JSON_Value (EMP.VALUE, '$.emp_no') as.....
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding 'N' before your sql set to indicate that unicode characters are contained within like this:

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)

set @JSON=N'[{
"emp_no": "001",
"emp_designation":"Data Admin",
"emp_name": "Peter",
"emp_name2": "彼特"},
 {
"emp_no": "002",
"emp_designation":"Software Engineer",
"emp_name": "Lee",
"emp_name2": "李"
 }]'
```

This question may assist in background:
 [What does N' stands for in a SQL script ? (the one used before characters in insert script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353238/what-does-n-stands-for-in-a-sql-script-the-one-used-before-characters-in-ins)

Comment: Sorry that I do not mention clearly,  actually my JSON is a parameter inside a Stored Procedure.

I cannot simply put an 'N' in front of it, if I try to do something like this:
 
  set JSON =  'N' + JSON
 

I will hit an error, since the N will cause the an error of invalid JSON format.

Comment: @CheeHouNg How do you call the stored procedure? Show the code.

Comment: @Tomalak

Just a normal c# code:


`var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var JsonString = serializer.Serialize(List_EmpInfo);

    string connS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_Connn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connS);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_StoreEmpInfo", connection)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Json", JsonString);`

Comment: sorry, I'm new at here, the code might look dirty, because I have no idea how to do newline in SO's comment section.

Comment: This should work, .NET strings are Unicode and parameter datatypes are normally inferred properly. You can try adding the parameter with an explicit `SqlDbType.NVarChar` data type, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992741/18771.

Comment: @Tomalak
it works with the following code
 `cmd.Parameters.Add("@JsonString", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1);`

Thanks.