# Arabic text shows as question marks in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ShrinxUser`@`%` PROCEDURE `AddRec`(IN `p_App` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8, IN `p_Code` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8, IN `p_DT` DATETIME, IN `p_IP` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8, IN `p_Field` VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8, IN `p_Value` VARCHAR(4000) CHARSET utf8)
BEGIN 


INSERT INTO Rec (App, Code, DT, IP, Field, Value) 
VALUES (p_App, p_Code, p_DT, p_IP, p_Field, p_Value);

End
```

When I call it like this

```
Call AddRec('Test','2399399','12 May 20', ':::1','sss','أكرم');
```

I get arabic text fine in the database

but when I call it from C# asp.net I get ????

I debugged my C# asp.net code and I noticed that C# reads the arabic text fine.

It sends it in arabic but stored in DB as ?????

here is my C# code

```
            //First Name
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("p_App", "Test"));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("p_Code", "1345"));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("p_DT", "20 mar 2020"));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("p_IP", "1234"));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("p_Field", "Name"));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("p_Value", "محمد"));
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How to fix that?!

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2000154/2892829) answer.

Comment: @Orifjon This answer is for SQL Server, I want MySQL

Comment: https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434

Comment: utf8 -> utf8mb4

Comment: still now working, gettting ??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `CharSet=utf8mb4` to your connection string to make sure that UTF-8 is used to send data to and from the database. (MySQL Server frequently has `latin1` as the default character set, and it can't express non-Latin characters.)

Better yet, update to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), which always uses UTF-8 to transmit data (and [fixes many other bugs](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs)).

Also use `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8` wherever you can; MySQL's `utf8` [is not actually UTF-8](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434) and will lose data (e.g., if trying to store emoji characters).

Comment: Thanks, utf8mb4 gave error but CharSet=utf8 worked fine.